# Rails asking for a secret key to create model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I am creating a simple blog / news website without a user authentication system. I've decided to a use plain some sort of secret key checking technique to allow visitors who know the key to make posts.

In short, to post, you have to provide a key. Otherwise, it object should not be saved into the db.

Here's my code.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :slaptazodis

  validate :passcheck
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true

  def passcheck

    if :slaptazodis != "1234"
      errors.add(:base, 'Invalid pass')
    end
  end
end
```

So, I create a new model in sandbox with title, body and attribute slaptazodis set to 1234. Still, when I check errors, console keeps showing me "Invalid pass". What am I doing wrong? Is it about attributes or something? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider putting that logic away from the post model and moving it to the controller.

In the controller you could check the parameters sent by an user eg.

```
if params[:slaptazodis] != "1234"
```

If however, you're learning rails and just want to make it work with your existing solution, change from:

```
if :slaptazodis != "1234"
```

to:

```
if slaptazodis != "1234"
```

The ":" tells Rails that it should consider the characters following a *symbol* (almost the same as a string) just for clarification, your code is therefore *almost* the same as say:

```
if "slaptazodis" != "1234"
```

Which of course always renders true.

Comment: May I ask you why is it I do not need to use : before the variable? The thing is, me, myself, I wouldn't put it there, but some guy told me I had to. I still don't quite get it.

Comment: @LukasValatka Look into this explanation: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/194870 and get back to be if you don't understand :-)