# Partial's parameters in rails aren't staying the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, local-variables

I'm trying to create an admin partial that has all the utility addons I need for my website in one file to reduce clutter, using a local I should be able to tell what part I need based of the string that I pass as a local.

= render 'admin/projects', locals: { utility: "delete" }

and in my _projects

```
- if request.subdomain == 'admin'
  -if :utility == "delete"
    %button.delete
```

When run no button appears, if set to != 'delete' a button appears.

Why isn't my variable being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a string to a symbol, you probably want to write:

```
- if request.subdomain == 'admin'
  -if utility == "delete"
    %button.delete
```

Your render syntax is also a bit off, instead of:

```
= render 'admin/projects', locals: { utility: "delete" }
```

Use

```
= render :partial => 'admin/projects', locals: { utility: "delete" }
```

I answered a similar question earlier here: [Rails asking for a secret key to create model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174207/rails-asking-for-a-secret-key-to-create-model/22174315#22174315)

Comment: I wish, it's undefiend unless its a symbol, undefined local variable or method `utility

Comment: Try to update your render syntax to: = render :partial => 'admin/projects', locals: { utility: "delete" }

Comment: It was the partial declaration I was missing that caused it to not work. Thanks for the spot!

Comment: That thing used to take up alot of time for me aswell in the beginning - and it's hard to spot!